# How can I break out of a for loop when using JOptionPanes?

Tags: java, for-loop, joptionpane, break

I have a huge problem that I've been working on and for the life of me, cannot get this right. From what I have gathered as of now, I am unable to exit my for loop when I'm using JOptionPanes, because it will never reach it for some reason, even when the code is right underneath.

The goal of my code is to iterate through a .CSV file and the user will input a series of inputs, most notably, I'm checking for duplicates, and if a duplicate is found, then I will proceed to display a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog, and break the for loop after the message has displayed.

However, my message dialog keeps looping and won't go any further, so I'm stuck on as what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, myPanel, "Edit Fruit", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        for (row = 0; row < myEntries.size(); row++)
        {
            for (column = 0; column < myEntries.get(row).length; column++)
            {
                //If serial exists
                if (myEntries.get(row)[column].trim().equals(newSerial.getText()))
                {
                    //break loop
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Serial already exists!");
                    break;
                //If the serial does not exist, write this new line to the end of the file        
                }else if (!(myEntries.get(row)[column].trim().equals(newSerial.getText())))
                {
                    System.out.println(row);
                    myEntries.add(new String[] {newSerial.getText(), dateFormat.format(newDate), newLocation.getText(), 
                    "",newAllocation, newCondition, newType.getText(), newComments.getText()});
                }

            }
```

If my document contains a "6", and I search for that, this code will iterate through both if statements for some reason, and just won't break.

What is meant to happen is, my for loop will iterate through my text file until it finds an exact match from the users input, and if so, break. If a duplicate is not found, then append the new line of code to the end of the file.

It's just not working and I'm not sure where to go from here, so I'm hoping someone here can help.

If you need any more information, then please let me know so I can provide and get this problem fixed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you intend to `break` the first loop, you can use [labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7)

```
OUTER: for (row = 0; row < myEntries.size(); row++) {
    for (column = 0; column < myEntries.get(row).length; column++) {
        // If serial exists
        if (myEntries.get(row)[column].trim().equals(newSerial.getText())) {
            // break loop
            OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Serial already exists!");
            break OUTER;
        // If the serial does not exist, write this new line to the end of the file
        } else if (!(myEntries.get(row)[column].trim().equals(newSerial.getText()))) {
            System.out.println(row);
            myEntries.add(new String[] { newSerial.getText(), dateFormat.format(newDate), newLocation.getText(), "", newAllocation, newCondition, newType.getText(), newComments.getText() });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Note, that you only need the label on the outer loop as the inner one is not used. Also, the most common convention for this construct is, to label the outer loop "OUTER" and then break OUTER.

Answer (score 1):

You need one more `break`.

```
for (row = 0; row < myEntries.size(); row++)
{
    for (column = 0; column < myEntries.get(row).length; column++)
    {
        //If serial exists
        if (myEntries.get(row)[column].trim().equals(newSerial.getText()))
        {
            //break loop
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Serial already exists!");
            break;
            //If the serial does not exist, write this new line to the end of the file        
        } else if (!(myEntries.get(row)[column].trim().equals(newSerial.getText())))
        {
            System.out.println(row);
            myEntries.add(new String[] {newSerial.getText(), dateFormat.format(newDate), newLocation.getText(), "",newAllocation, newCondition, newType.getText(), newComments.getText()});
        }
   }
   break; // <- This is required to break from outer loop.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much, however, even if it does find a duplicate, it still prints the row and appends to my text file, twice. What is the go with that, am I doing something wrong?